# texstudio doesnt add new works to dictionary via context menu

Tags: texstudio, linux, spelling, dictionaries

I have TeXstudio 2.10.8 in Ubuntu 16.10. When I right click on misspelled word and try to add it manually by selecting "add to dictionary", it doesn't work and later the word will be marked as misspelled again.

I know that it is possible to manually edit the dic file, but I would like to use "add to dictionary" from context menu which is easier and faster.

Needless to say, dictionary and each part of TeXstudio works perfect.

Comment: Any comment? Anybody with texstudio on Linux who doesnt have this problem?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: the answer is good but it doesn't solve the problem. I need practical steps so that after performing the steps, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

From the [TeXstudio Manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION03):

> Since the internal structure of the dictionaries is complex (e.g. contains rules how to generate a word with in different inflections) it is not possible to simply add words to the dictionary. Instead if a word is missing in the dictionary, you can add it to an ignore list, so that the spell checker won't complain about it. The ignore list is normally saved in the same directory as the dictionary. It's a plain text file with the extension .ign. If this isn't possible (e.g. missing access rights) the list is stored in the user configuration directory.

Check if the .ign file is written when you close TXS.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the access right to the `*.ign` file, e.g. `<Spell\DictionaryDir>\en_US.ign` where `<Spell\DictionaryDir>` is what ever is defined in **Options --> Configure TexStudio... --> Language Checking -> Spell Check**.

If not, either move that directory to another location (like `~\texstudio\dictionaries`) or change the permissions with:

```
cd <Spell\DictionaryDir>
chmod ugo+w en_US.ign
```